# What can I do with some whipped cream and egg yolk mix?

Tags: cream, yolk

I had a bit of a cooking disaster last night, where I was trying to make a tiramisu using a recipe I'd never used before.

The recipe called for mixing marscapone and egg yolks, but I  was using cream instead. I was hoping the cream would whip and be fluffy, but after 10 minutes beating it looks like it was never going get fluffy. So I've got a mixture of about 1 litre of cream, 5 egg yolks, 100gm sugar, and some Marsala. It's a light liquid.

It tastes quite nice, but isn't suitable for a tiramisu.

What can I do with it?

Comment: It sounds like an eggnog base -- perhaps add more alcohol, some whipped egg whites on top, and a sprinkle of nutmeg?

Comment: Cream needs to have close to 36% milk fat to emulsify, if the cream you are using is close to this content, next time try adding a some powdered sugar or using a really cold bowl to mix it in.  You have a bread pudding base right now or something similar.

Comment: @Chef_Code - Good suggestion re: bread pudding. Post it as an answer.

Answer (score 6):

What you have sounds like a cross between a zabaione and a custard.

Depending on what equipment you have, you might consider:

- heating it slowly in a double boiler while whipping it.
- chill it, then use it to make ice cream.

It's likely too runny to use as a soufle base (fold it into whipped egg whites, then bake).  You might be able to augment it with more egg yolks, or try cooking it like in the first item, then adding it to the egg whites.

**update:** one more possiblity:

- use it as the custard for french toast.

Comment: Cook it gently and call it custard was my first thought on reading the question.

Answer (score 5):

I would use the base as a bread pudding base.  If you have some stale bread, or even bread that will eventually become stale (it really depends on preference), and some raisins or any dehydrated fruit, this would make some tasty bread pudding.

Re-hydrate the fruit with some of the alcohol.

Heck, you might even have a favorite bread pudding recipe.

Comment: Tasty! I think I may need to start adding Marsala to my bread pudding...

Answer (score 2):

As Erica says in the comments, it would make a great eggnog. Add some hard alcohol (there are lots of recipes out there - bourbon, rum, brandy, or some combo). Whip the egg whites and then beat them lightly into the nog. Sprinkle with nutmeg, serve. The amounts you have will make a nog that has a higher cream:egg ratio than most, but it should still taste quite good. Here are a couple recipe links to give you some ideas.

http://www.foodnetwork.com/recipes/alton-brown/eggnog-recipe2.html

http://www.chow.com/recipes/10758-best-eggnog

http://www.epicurious.com/recipes/food/views/eggnog-201146

Answer (score 0):

You can bake a custard or crème brûlée using the mixture and baking in a pan placed in a casserole dish 1/2 full of water on 300 degree F for 40 to 50 min., it will look jiggly still. Then top with 2 Tbsp. sugar and return to oven for 10 to 15 min. more. Turn off oven and keep closed letting it set for 30 more min. in oven. Open door and set for 30 min. more. Either freeze for 1 hr. or refrigerate 2 to 3 hours.